# Azure PowerShell alias

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cli

I see many answers to questions about Azure where the answer is you have to execute a series of commands like these:

```
azure vm image list-publishers westus
azure vm image list-offers westus MicrosoftWindowsServer 
azure vm image list-skus westus MicrosoftWindowsServer WindowsServer
```

from [Service Fabric Application vmImageSku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286479/service-fabric-application-vmimagesku)

This is just one random example out of many.

How do you translate statements like that into command that works?

I feel I am missing some step in my configuration of my environment.
I have just started a normal powershell console and are working in that. 
I have not imported anything azure specific into the console but have Visual Studio 2017 and latest azure sdk installed on the box.

Comment: Do you mean you can't run those commands in your powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [*install* the **azure cli**:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cli-install-nodejs)

Note that there is already a [version 2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli) of the CLI which uses the `az` keyword which you might prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Those commands are **not** Azure PowerShell commands. As Martin said, to run those commands, you should install CLI 1.0.
We can use Azure PowerShell commands to get those information:

> azure vm image list-publishers westus

`Get-AzureRmVMImagePublisher -Location westus`

> azure vm image list-offers westus MicrosoftWindowsServer

`Get-AzureRmVMImageOffer -Location westus -PublisherName MicrosoftWindowsServer`

> azure vm image list-skus westus MicrosoftWindowsServer WindowsServer

```
Get-AzureRmVMImageSku -Location westus -PublisherName MicrosoftWindowsServer -Offer WindowsServer
```